# Modern Warfare 3 Multiplayer is "Currently Unavailable?"

Tags: steam, technical-issues, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I started up Steam today to play some Modern Warfare 3, and finally play for more than 10 minute increments... Regardless the reason for me playing, the game would not start- and notified me:

"This game is currently unavailable. Please try again at another time."

My internet connection is working perfectly, as I am posting this question. Are the servers under maintenance, or have I somehow done something wrong?

Comment: hi just started having the same problem. it's not just you. i'm hoping it's because activision is making the multiplayer less laggy but we'll see haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a pretty common Steam issue.  You might want to check out this [help topic](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4595-WEXN-6831) on the Steam support site.

Comment: Ah, yes, never heard of this before. I tried a few things, and I got one to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a bit late, but the other thing that worked for me was to just update modern warfare 3, it was 4.5mb and after that the game ran perfectly.